# Is the Q&A format optimal for code review?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I'm new here, but it seems to me that the Q&A format isn't necessarily the best option for code review.

It's been my experience when asking for code review that I don't know exactly what I am asking for. That's why I am here asking for the code review in the first place. I am not looking for one particular answer, I am looking for reviews of my code.

Am I wrong here? Has anyone else noticed this being awkward? Despite this I still plan on using the site. I'm just not sure how to go about selecting "the answers." I was surprised to not find anything on this here (maybe I didn't look hard enough.)

One idea is to do something like allowing multiple accepted answers.

**Update** I understand the challenge. Code Review is an instance of a particular product. The goal of that product is to support a Q&A based community. What I think I'm taking away from the discussion is this: we aren't necessarily looking for one single "accepted-answer." So I will upvote the answers that I find useful. Thanks Jamal and 200_success.

Comment: Consider marking the "accepted answer" as just granting a bit of extra reputation to the one you found most helpful rather than saying "This one is right, all the others are wrong."  That's how I think about it on here.

Comment: Jeff Gohlke: I think the problem is that an accepted answer says "there's nothing more to add here" and that seems to only apply to code review questions that are highly specific.

Answer (score 11):

> One idea is to do something like allowing multiple accepted answers.

The problem with this is that the single-answer acceptance system is consistent throughout all SE sites.  Despite this one site's intentions, it cannot be implemented just for us.  I agree that the accepted answer system has its flaws, but I don't see any changing in it any time soon.  [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is the FAQ entry about it on Meta Stack Overflow.

Beyond that, you are not obligated to accept an answer under any circumstances.  It is nice to give a great an answer an extra reward, and there are times when it's hard to choose the "best" answer.  Other times, *no* answer seems worthy of being accepted.  You, as the OP, get to choose when and when not to accept an answer.

Although not entirely related, there's the [bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).  This will allow you to reward more answers, *but* at the expense of your own rep.

Comment: This all makes sense. It sounds like nothing is in the works then?

Comment: I don't think so.  It would not make too much sense, either.  Accepted answers can also tell visitors which answer is worth checking out first.  If there are several accepted ones, it'll be harder to determine which one the OP really found to be the best.

Comment: By "cannot be implemented", you mean "it wouldn't be worth the effort"? (Assuming everyone agreed that multiple accepted answers is the right thing to do for CR.)

Comment: @svick: Yes, I think so.  I'd first want to see just how this system would work.  Still, I'm not sure if something like this can even go onto one site and not every site.

Answer (score 10):

There is already a mechanism to acknowledge multiple good answers: the upvote.

Answer (score 2):

The feature that I find most missing here is inline comments (like [Cruicible](https://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/overview)). Perphaps just being able to place dots (or other tags) inline w/ id that could be used to focus on "answer" below would be sufficient.

Otherwise it can be hard to follow discussion of a code section that is not very short.